# Rspec unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

It works fine:

```
post :create, params_with_product
```

and it too:

```
 put :update, id:@item, item: params_with_product
```

But it fails with syntax error syntax error, `unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'` when I do:

```
put :update, :id => @item.id, params_with_product
```

Where:

```
let(params_with_product) { item: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:item_without_product) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `put :update, { :id => @item.id }.merge(params_with_product)`

Answer (score 1):

Just adding with djaszczurowski's answer which is correct.

For [request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) you have to send `params` hash (`key: value` pairs) as argument to the request where `value` can be a hash itself. So, `post`, `put` methods can take a `params` hash as an argument.

In your first case, it worked:

```
post :create, params_with_product
```

because `params_with_product` is a hash (valid `key: value` pair)

But, in the second case:

```
put :update, :id => @item.id, params_with_product
```

it failed because the second param doesn't have any `key`. 
So, you can just merge `:id => @item.id` with the `params_with_product` which returns a hash again (valid `key: value` pairs) and works fine.

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam, updated my question a little bit, when `id: @item, item: param_with_product` is a hash then why this one won't be? I did not understand that part.

Comment: `put :update, id:@item, item: params_with_product` works because you have `key => value` pair for both of your params. But, `put :update, :id => @item.id, params_with_product` fails because you have `key => value` pair for the first param but not for the second one. So, either you have to send all the param as `key: value` pair, or you can merge them into one hash which has all the `key: value` pairs. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any other question. Thanks.